# Why redux initial state will be undefined when reducers don't have "default"?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I don't know why the initial state will be 'undefined' if I don't write 'default'?

```
function counter(state = 1,action){
    switch(action.type){
        case 1:
            return state + 1;
        case 2:
            return state - 1;
    }
}

const store = createStore(counter);

let currentValue = store.getState();

const listener = () => {
    const previousValue = currentValue;
    currentValue = store.getState();
    console.log('pre',previousValue,'current',currentValue);
}

store.subscribe(listener);

store.dispatch({type:1});//pre undefined current 2
store.dispatch({type:1});//pre 2 current 3
store.dispatch({type:2});//pre 3 current 2
```

But when I write this:

```
import { createStore } from 'redux';

function counter(state = 1,action){
    switch(action.type){
        case 1:
            return state + 1;
        case 2:
            return state - 1;
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

const store = createStore(counter);

let currentValue = store.getState();
const listener = () => {
    const previousValue = currentValue;
    currentValue = store.getState();
    console.log('pre',previousValue,'current',currentValue);
}

store.subscribe(listener);

store.dispatch({type:1});//pre 1 current 2
store.dispatch({type:1});//pre 2 current 3
store.dispatch({type:2});//pre 3 current 2
```

The only difference is "default" in "switch function". I don't know why it became `undefined` because I think the `store` should return initial-state => '0' before execute `dispatch`.

Comment: Because you're not returning anything, which leads to `undefined` in JS.

Comment: Please don't use snippets if the code isn't supposed to run. Just use normal code blocks. I've edited the question for you.

Comment: thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Redux will do an initial run and go through all of your reducers immediately on start, even before you dispatch an action. So essentially at that point in time your state is undefined, because you have not returned an initial state value in your reducer. When you set a default case in your switch statement and return the assigned state, this is what your state will be on first run.